# clearInterval not stopping function having callout pulse of velocity.js started by setInterval

Tags: javascript, jquery, velocity.js

I am using velocity.js for pulse animation.
I have simple code
In html I have :
    XXXXXXXXXXX

In javascript:
    var blinkNext = 0;  // Global variable

```
    var blinkBtn = function() {
        $("div").velocity("callout.pulse");
        };

blinkNext = setInterval(blinkBtn, 1);


clearInterval(blinkNext);   // <-- Not working
```

Expected behavior: div section should pulse and then get stopped.
Problem: clearInterval is not stopping pulse callout.
I searched alot but couldn't found anything

Comment: Any errors? Can you replicate the problem in a fiddle if possible.

Comment: There was no error in the javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the interval set to just a single millisecond, so you are calling `.velocity()` every millisecond, and I assume those calls queue up. So when you clear the interval, it is going to take a very long time for the animation to stop.

Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fwu2gqer/1/) that demonstrates the problem with the original code. Click "Run >" and then click the "stop" button as fast as you can. You can see how many times "blink" is written to the console log. That is how many times the animation will run before it stops, but it will eventually stop.

Instead of using `setInterval()`, you could do the following:

```
var blinking = true;

function blink() {
    $('#btnNext').velocity('callout.pulse', function() {
        // This anonymous function is called when the animation completes.
        // If we should be blinking, then we call blink() again.
        if (blinking) {
            blink();
        }
    });
}

// Initially start the animation.
blink();

// This button shows how you can stop and restart the animation.
$('#toggleBtn').click(function() {
    blinking = !blinking;
    if (blinking) {
        blink();
    }
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p5s6rzk3/)

Comment: Thanx alot. This was really helpful. For now I increased the interval size to 1000 ms . Things started working now.